# Ajax loaded part of a page - how do I make links in the loaded content work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I load a part of my basketpage inside an accordion div in my header. This works great and shows my basket in a nice dropdown.

The last problem I need to solve with this is to get the buttons in the loaded content to work. Is it possible to write an callback that make these works? Im not sure even what to google for this one..

This is how the buttons is setup in the loaded content:

```
<a href="" trg="" name="_ec_oie2" id="_ec_oie2" class="action actionbasket checkout" onclick="if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">checkout</a>
```

Script Im using to load the content:

```
 $('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox');
```

Comment: By using `load()` with fragment url, you aren't loading `script` including `UI.pb_boolean()` method. What you could done is using instead `$.get()` method and parse relevant html data returned, including specific `script` tag

Comment: @ A.Wollf Could you construct a simple example for me to look at? Thanks!

Comment: It would be something like that: `$.get('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket', function(html){
  var $content = $('<div/>').html(html);
  var $div = $content.find('div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox').prop('outerHTML');
  var $scripts = $content.find('script');
  $('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').html($div);
  $('head').append($scripts);
});`  Not tested but give you the idea. You should have to use `$.getScript()` to process scripts, not sure about that (or use native js way to append script in HEAD)

Comment: EDIT: i understood that your issue is `UI.pb_boolean()` beeing undefined in main page, otherwise, forget my comments. But if you have error in console, you have to post it

Answer (score 0):

use the callback function of [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

```js
$('.dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu').load('/m4n?seid=etailer-basket div#centerbox.itembox.centerbox', function() {
  $("#_ec_oie2").on("click", function() {
    if (UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click')) { }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" trg="" name="_ec_oie2" id="_ec_oie2" class="action actionbasket checkout">checkout</a>
```

Comment: Hi! this didnt seems to work - not sure why- Looks solid.

Comment: try putting an alert("Test") in the click function

Comment: Well I don't think that would work. When I click  the link it goes to /exception which is the page I end up when there's an error. Its a web shop built for my company - but something we don't have too much control over.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a child selector for the event. You can attach an event to the `.sub-menu` element that will fire on the content loaded in through the ajax. Something like the following could work:

```
$(".dcjqg-accordion ul.sub-menu").on("click", ".action.actionbasket.checkout", function() {
    if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {}
    return false;
});
```

Notice the second parameter to the `on` method. It is a selector that will be used to look at the target of the click event. I used `.action.actionbasket.checkout` since that is what is on your `a` tag.

This code may not work exactly, but this should help get you in the right direction.

Here is the link to the jQuery documentation for the `on` method: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks fr the reply. Unfortunaly it didnt seem to work, i will look into the on method. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Xeptor. If you put a console.log() statement in the callback function, does that show up when you click the links? I don't know exactly what that if block is doing. Also, try changing the ".action.actionbasket.checkout" to just one of those classes like ".action".

Comment: Hi tim. the problem is that when I click the link it goes to /exception which is the page I end up when there's an error on the system Im working on, so that wont work.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the link is clicked?

Comment: @Tim Banks working from home and I don't remember the login so writing from another user - there is a few buttons. one updates the basket, one goes to the checkout, one removes products. The a links all have the same onlick script inside them though.

Comment: I tried to load the whole url into my body tag for giggles to se what happends. aside from things looking really wierd, the button did work. I guess my problem would be it wont load the correct scripts?